# Inserir minuto a minuto na função

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte função php abaixo:

```
function showComboHorarios($name, $default = '08:00') {
$hi = 6;  // hora inicial
$hf = 23; // hora final
?>
<select style="width: 80px;" name="<?php echo $name; ?>">
    <?php
    for ($i = $hi; $i <= $hf; $i++) {
        $h = ($i < 10) ? '0' . $i : $i;
        $h .= ':';
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $h . '00'; ?>"<?php echo ($default == $h . '00') ? ' selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $h . '00'; ?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo $h . '30'; ?>"<?php echo ($default == $h . '30') ? ' selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $h . '30'; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
<?php
}
```

e em seguida exibe a tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, estou tentando inserir um for minuto a minuto nessa mesma função:

```
function showComboHorarios($name, $default = '08:00') {
$hi = 6;  // hora inicial
$hf = 23; // hora final
?>
<select style="width: 80px;" name="<?php echo $name; ?>">
    <?php
    for ($i = $hi; $i <= $hf; $i++) {
        $h = ($i < 10) ? '0' . $i : $i;
        $h .= ':';
            for ($min = 0; $min< 59; $min++){ 
        ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $h . $min  ?>"<?php echo ($default == $h . $min ) ? ' selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $h . $min  ?></option>
                <option value="<?php echo $h . $min ?>"<?php echo ($default == $h . $min) ? ' selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $h . $min; ?></option>
        <?php
            }//for mminuto
    }
    ?>
</select>
<?php
}
```

porém, na tela exibe assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como deixo no formato 00:00 ?

agradecido pela atenção.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formata a hora desta forma: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1699980

sprintf('%02d:%02d', $h, $min);

Comment: obrigado, deu certo utilizando a função sprintf

Answer (score 3):

Faz um "if" dentro do "for" dos minutos.

```
if ($min < 10) {
    $min_correto = '0' . $min
} else {
    $min_correto = $min;
}
```

ai você coloca a variável $min_correto para ser exibida no lugar de $min